# Check duplicates latitudes and longitudes

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to make work this code that I found in some thread here.

```js
var values= [{lat: 12345, lng: 54321},{lat: 98765, lng: 54321}, {lat: 99999, lng: 111111} ]

let seen = new Set();
var hasDuplicates = values.some(function(currentObject) {
    return seen.size === seen.add(currentObject.lng).size;
});
console.log(hasDuplicates)
```

It says it's true but It's not because it's only checking if the longitude exist by its own not WITH the latitude.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain what should be the expected result?

Comment: It says it's true in the console log BUT it should print false because no latitude and longitude are duplicated (in the same obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, convert the `currentObject` to a string representation and use that as the Set values.

```
seen.add(currentObject.lat + " " + currentObject.lng)
```

```js
var values= [{lat: 12345, lng: 54321},{lat: 12345, lng: 54321}, {lat: 99999, lng: 111111} ]

let seen = new Set();
var hasDuplicates = values.some(function(currentObject) {
    return seen.size === seen.add(currentObject.lat + " " + currentObject.lng).size;
});
console.log(hasDuplicates)
```

Comment: Nops, that doesn't work because If I change the values array into this: 

var values= [{lat: 12345, lng: 54321},{lat: 12345, lng: 54321}, {lat: 99999, lng: 111111} ]

It'll say false BUT the first and the second elements are duplicate

Comment: I just run the code and it says `true` for me, I edit the answer with the code.

Comment: It was the size at the end of that string, nice ;)